# Re-scaling Neural Network Outputs Appropriatel

Tags: neural-network

I'm currently working on a ANN (feed forward MLP via neurolab), and have trained my network to do a linear regression of ~40 data points to a single value, e.g.

> 350, 10, -6.3, ...., -9.78
>
> 12 , 5 , -2.5, ...., -8.23
>
> 5  , 18, -10 , ...., -8.78

And so on, with the last column being my target value. However, in the process, I scale all of the data to be -1 < x < 1 (keying off of max and min values for each feature). After running my calculations, I am now needing to 'un-scale' or 're-scale' my data back to the appropriate range (e.g. from -1 < x < 1 to X < x < Y. The 'obvious' solution is to re-scale the data using something akin to:

> I = Imin + (Imax-Imin)*(X-Dmin)/(Dmax-Dmin)

However, won't this 'rescaling' of my data force my predictions to be within the same window (e.g. max and min values) of my training data? It would seem that some of my predictions should be able to fall well outside of the original training data. Is there a way to re-scale the data in a less constrictive manner?

Comment: Slightly re-worded (upon further thinking):

Is it true that a linear regression MLP network can only make predictions that fall inbetween the min and max values of your training target data?

Comment: Just answered my own question! Found the following:
"""
We can replace the logistic output activation function with a linear activation function, which simply passes on the activation level unchanged (N.B. only the activation functions in the output layer are changed; the hidden layers still use logistic or hyperbolic activation functions).

Comment: Ok, so only partially answered the question. The correct method is to use a linear activation transfer function on the output, but the question of how to appropriately scale the data remains. I don't want to force the scale of my output to match that explicitly that of the input. What if my extrapolations (via linear activation) would naturally fall outside the range of my training data?

Comment: If you want to use a linear activation function, then don't scale your targets at all.